# Cannot find_one record in MongoDB with custom _id's

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, motor-asyncio

I have a MongoDB database where I overwrote the `_id` field manually using some generated tags (duplicates are not an issue).

Trouble is, I am trying to `find_one` searching by `_id` but it continuously returns `None` and I cannot figure it out for the life of me. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code I have so far:

```py
async def update(self):
        #self.input is part of my class variables and comes in as a string
        client = AsyncIOMotorClient(sensitive_data.mongoDB_server_address) #sensitive data is another python file with the server address/usernae/password
        db = client.Database
        accounts = db.accounts
        print(type(self.input)) #this prints string
        account = await accounts.find_one({'_id':self.input})
        print(account) #this prints none
        return account
```

Edit:

I found some information on pyMongo documentation about `ObjectID`. I tried implementing it with this code:

```py
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

async def update(self):
        #self.input is part of my class variables and comes in as a string
        client = AsyncIOMotorClient(sensitive_data.mongoDB_server_address) #sensitive data is another python file with the server address/usernae/password
        db = client.Database
        accounts = db.accounts
        print(type(self.input)) #this prints string
        account = await accounts.find_one({'_id':ObjectID(self.input)})
        print(account) #this prints none
        return account
```

But get this traceback:
`bson.errors.InvalidId: 'mystring' is not a valid ObjectId, it must be a 12-byte input or a 24-character hex string`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was trying to find an ID in a database that didn't exist. Oops.